# Python editing imported method

Tags: python, python-import, enthought, canopy

I'm writing a python file that imports a method which I wrote. This method is still buggy, so I need to be able to edit it. The issue is if I edit the imported method, the file that is calling that method won't register any of the changes I've made. The only way I've been able to get the changes registered is to exit out completely (I'm using Enthought Canopy). I've tried clearing out all the variables with %reset, exiting all my open .py files, and then opening them again and running them. It doesn't work.

I can combine the two files so that the method is being called inside the .py file in which it is written, but as I will need the method for a lot of applications, this is only a short-term fix since I don't want any extraneous code in the file long-term.

Comment: Have you tried [`reload`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload)?